# New coordinate of another point after rotating one point on $S^2$?

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

As we rotate $p_a = (x_a, y_a, z_a)$ to $p_b = (x_b, y_b, z_b)$ (both are known), how can we find the the new location of $p_c = (x_c, y_c, z_c)$ after this rotation? Can we instead find out the new location of $\overrightarrow{p_a p_c}$ after this rotation? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I can find the rotation axis $r_{p_a p_c}$ of $\overrightarrow{p_a p_c}$ by taking the cross product of $\overrightarrow{p_a}$ and $\overrightarrow{p_c}$ because that axis is sure both perpendicular to both position vectors. But how can we find out the rotation angle to rotate $p_a$ to $p_b$ along $r_{p_a p_c}$?

Comment: There isn't a unique solution. Consider this simple example. We have 2 points on a sphere, with A on the equator at longitude 0 and B at the north pole. Now rotate the sphere so A is at the north pole. B is now on the equator, but it can be at any longitude.

Answer (score 1):

Let unit vectors
$$\hat{a} = \frac{p_a}{\lVert p_a \rVert} \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{b} = \frac{p_b}{\lVert p_b \rVert}$$
*One* way to rotate $\hat{a}$ to $\hat{b}$ is to rotate around unit axis vector $\hat{n}$ by angle $\theta$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{n} &= \hat{a} \times \hat{b} \\
\hat{n} &= \frac{\vec{n}}{\lVert\vec{n}\rVert} \\
\cos\theta &= \hat{a} \cdot \hat{b} \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\times$ denotes vector cross product, and $\cdot$ dot product.